# differences between new and malloc in c++

Tags: c++, malloc, dynamic-allocation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Box {
   public:
      Box() {
         cout << "Constructor called!" <<endl;
      }
      void printer(int x)
    {
        cout<<x<<" printer"<<endl;
    }

      ~Box() {
         cout << "Destructor called!" <<endl;
      }

};

int main( ) {
    Box* myBoxArray = new Box[4];

    Box* myBoxArray2 = (Box*)malloc(sizeof(Box[4]));
    myBoxArray2->printer(23);
    *myBoxArray2;
    *(myBoxArray2).printer(23);

   return 0;
}
```

the problem simply is that when i use 'new' the constructor is printed out but when i simple derefrence the pointer to `myBoxArray2` the constructor is not printed and neither is the funtion `printer` printed. 
Also why is it that when i use `->` the funnction printer runs but not when i use the equivalent `*(myBoxArray2).printer(23)`

Comment: Your use of `malloc()` is invalid here. Class instances must be allocated on the stack, or via `new`. When you use `malloc()` none of the C++ machinery is invoked.

Comment: `myBoxArray2` is just a pointer to some memory space that's the size of -  well, the size of something that's irrelevant. Even if you copied `myBoxArray` into that space, it's never going to call the constructor, because - wait for it - it's not being constructed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`malloc` allocates memory *only*, it doesn't invoke constructors which can leave objects in an indeterminate state.

In C++ you should almost *never* use `malloc`, `calloc` or `free`. And if possible avoid `new` and `new[]` as well, use object instances or vectors of instances instead.

---

As for your second question (which is really unrelated to the first), `*(myBoxArray2).printer(23)` is *wrong* since the the `.` selection operator have higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the dereference operator `*`. That means first of all that you use the `.` member selector on a pointer which is invalid, and that you attempt to dereference what `printer` returns which is also wrong since it doesn't return anything.

You want `(*myBoxArray2).printer(23)` (note the location of the asterisk is *inside* the parentheses), which is *exactly* the same as `myBoxArray2->printer(23)`.

Also note that `myBoxArray2->printer(23)` is the same as `myBoxArray2[0].printer(23)`.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that malloc allocates memory without initializing it at all. On the other hand, `new` calls the appropriate constructor to initialize that memory (if that constructor is made to initialize that memory) and do other stuff to make a class usable.

Also `delete` calls the destructor for you.

Rule of thumb is: Never use `malloc` with C++, unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: Unless you really know what you're doing (and why you're doing it) - hence the constructor new.

Comment: Even if you know what you're doing you should still *probably* not do it. The compiler might make assumptions about how those objects are initialized due to optimizations and violating that is an express ticket to "Undefined Behaviour".